# How to make `helm-projectile-grep` do a recursive search?

Tags: grep, helm-projectile

I use helm with projectile and treemacs, how do I make helm-projectile-grep command to search in all project folders recursively starting at the project root. According to this page [helm-projectile](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) helm-projectile-grep should do it, but it does not. I've tested it and it only does grep in project root folder, or if you are in a file buffer that is deeply nested in folders it only does grep on the folder that the file is in. Any ideas? I specifically want to use helm and projectile with treemacs.